# In my android app textview.setText() method blocks ui thread for 2-3 seconds

Tags: android

I am trying to set a very long string.
and it's blocking UI thread for 2-3 Seconds.

In Async task only `doInBackground()` is in background,other functions use ui thread,I can't use `setText()` in background thread or in `doInBackground()`?is there any faster alternatives for textview?

Answer (score 1):

In onPostExecute() you can update the textview.

```
// This method runs on UI thread.
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         addResultToTextView(result);
}
```

Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set result of work into `onPostExecute()` of your async task

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Url, Integer, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        // for example, download something

        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
            // Escape early if cancel() is called
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return String.valueOf(totalSize);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Also, this example you can found in [AsyncTask usage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)